# summing nested dictionary values in python

Tags: python, dictionary

We represent scores of batsmen across a sequence of matches in a two level dictionary as follows:

```
{'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38}, 'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42}, 'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}
```

Each match is identified by a string, as is each player.  The scores are all integers.  The names associated with the matches are not fixed (here they are `match1`,`match2`,`match3`), nor are the names of the players.  A player need not have a score recorded in all matches

Define a Python function `orangecap(d)` that reads a dictionary d of this form and identifies the player with the highest total score.  Your function should return a pair `(playername,topscore)` where `playername` is a string, the name of the player with the highest score, and `topscore` is an integer, the total score of `playername`.

Comment: While it's ok to look for help with homework here, it is expected that you will try to solve the problem first, show the code you wrote, and describe how it's not working as you expect.

Comment: def orangecap(d):
    d = dict((key, sum(vals)) for key, vals in d.items())
    print(d)

Comment: Please click the ["edit"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42420650/edit) link under your question and add the code and description of what it's doing there.

Answer (score 1):

Summing up data and choose the highest value can often be accomplished with `collections.Counter()`, like so:

```
def orangecap(d):
    from collections import Counter
    return sum((Counter(game) for game in d.values()), Counter()).most_common(1)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Less pretty than Rob's answer but doesn't require any imports:

```
def orangecap(d):
    first_run = 1
    for match in d:
        for player in d[match]:
            if first_run == 1:
                first_run = 0
                topscore = d[match][player]
                playername = d[match]
            elif d[match][player] > topscore:
                topscore = d[match][player]
                playername = player

    return [playername, topscore]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a purposefully (!) lengthy and not particularly elegant solution which makes use of only fairly basic data structures, try/except, for loops and conditions. For a beginner, I suppose this might be more helpful to follow the logic of all the steps, i.e. the how and why of what is going on. I used descriptive variable names to make it easy to follow. The following code will also work if two or more players have the same total score:

```
game = {'match1': {'player1': 57, 'player2': 38},
        'match2': {'player3': 9, 'player1': 42},
        'match3': {'player2': 41, 'player4': 63, 'player3': 91},
        'match4': {'player1': 1}}


def orangecap(matches):
    players_and_scores = {}
    top_players_and_scores = []

    for match in matches:
        for player, score in matches[match].items():
            try:  # if key already exists
                players_and_scores[player] += score
            except:  # if key does not exist yet
                players_and_scores[player] = score

    # all players and their total stores:
    # print(players_and_scores)

    for player, score in players_and_scores.items():
        if score == max(players_and_scores.values()):
            top_players_and_scores.append((player, score))

    # return all top players (can be more than one)
    # and their total scores:
    return top_players_and_scores

print(orangecap(game))
```

Output:

```
[('player3', 100), ('player1', 100)]
```

Notice I added the key `match4` to the dictionary in order to have two players with the same total score.

Robᵩ's solution is much more concise and elegant and would be recommended if you can follow what it does and are allowed to use `collections.Counter()`. It will return only one of the players with the highest score, though, and might hence need some adjustment.